# Why is this switch statement printing the result twice?

Tags: jquery

I am doing codeacademy tutorial and I am really confuse why my code below is printing the result twice:

```
var getReview = function (movie) {

        switch(movie){

            case 'Toy Story 2':
                console.log("Great story. Mean prospector.");
                break;
            case 'Finding Nemo':
                console.log("Cool animation, and funny turtles.");
                break;
            case 'The Lion King':
                console.log("Great songs.");
                break;
            default:
                console.log("I don't know!");
        }


};

getReview("Toy Story 2");
```

This code is printing:

```
Great story. Mean prospector.
Great story. Mean prospector.
```

Can you help me, I am wondering why for days now. :(

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The code appears correct so the obvious conclusion is that you're accidentally calling `getReview` twice. Even though you don't show two calls in your question, I suspect you have them in your original code.

Comment: @mmahinay -- I just checked it in codepen and had no such issue...

Comment: It doesn't https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9fgdj4j8/

Comment: Thank you...I think it's a codeacademy console issue...I change to return instead of console.log

Comment: var getReview = function (movie) {

        switch(movie){
        
            case "Toy Story 2":
                return "Great story. Mean prospector.";
                break;
            case "Finding Nemo":
                return "Cool animation, and funny turtles.";
                break;
            case "The Lion King":
                return "Great songs.";
                break;
            default:
                return "I dont know!";
        }
       
  
};

getReview("Toy Story 2");

Comment: Thank you @anied -- it's okay now with using return :)

Comment: Thank you @j08691 for doing the jsfiddle :)